What is the meaning of 'to' in 'Archers been called to ranks'?
In the movie "Robin Hood", there is a line 'Archers been called to ranks' as shown below.
I can guess it means the archers have been shouted to or ordered to form ranks or lines (to prepare to shoot arrows).
I think the 'to' is a preposition.  What does the 'to' exactly mean in here?  Does it mean 'to form'? Could you provide similar or same usage of this 'to'?
Thank you very much.


"I can guess it means the archers have been shouted to or ordered to form ranks or lines (to prepare to shoot arrows)."  What else could it be? He was called upon to form a coalition of the willing. to here=purpose.

Called to ranks, to attention, to arms, etc. To a particular state.

The meeting has been called to order.  We need to discuss whether to call archers to ranks. If we can't decide, we'll be called to account.

Thank you all for the comments.  From more examples, I understand better.  For a non-native speaker, it is not easy to grasp the meaning the 'to' preposition in this sense.

One thing that might be confusing is that there would seem to be no verb in this sentence. Without viewing the video, my guess is that the captions are inaccurate and it's actually "The archers have been called to ranks," with the "have" perhaps contracted or mumbled. It's also possible that the line is delivered as it appears, with the omitted "have" being a bit of colorful dialogue giving a vague impression of old-timey roughness. (Note, dialogue in movies set before the modern period is usually not to be taken as in any way authentic. If there were a real Robin Hood, he would have been speaking Middle English, like this early reference to him:

Lytil Jhon and Robyne Hude
Wayth-men ware commendyd gude
In Yngil-wode and Barnysdale
Thai oysyd all this tyme thare trawale.

I've always thought it would be cool for a medieval-period movie to use real period language with subtitles, but I'm not aware of any that does. Instead they usually blend awkwardly modern usages with vaguely archaic or outdated patterns to make it "feel old," and the result is sometimes laughable and sometimes cheesy, but rarely something to study closely.
Next: the phrase "called to ranks" is fairly rare; it's not easy to find examples, but possible, like this late-19th-century usage:

About eleven o clock the troops were called to ranks and filed out to the grave dug just outside the camp by the road.

It seems clear that it should mean "summon to form orderly rows, or 'ranks.'"

Thank you Andy very much for the comment.  I know the 'have' is omitted and understood so.  My interest was the role or meaning of 'to' as a preposition in this sense.  I could not correctly find where the 'to' belongs in the preposition definition in the dictionary .  Thank you.

Prepositions have aspect, figuratively.  The aspect of to is akin to that of the perfect in achievement or end-state uses.
Compare:

Make it so.


Thank you TimR for the comment.  I am sorry my English is not good enough to quite understand how the 'to' compares to the phrase 'make it so'.  Is that referring the nautical term?  Thank you.

That is a command from StarTrek :-)   I was using it to express the idea of a state or goal being realized or achieved.   Consider:  He came to the door.  which expresses the idea of traversing the space between where he was and the door, until the door was reached.

Thank you TimR very much for further explanation.  I think I understand what you are getting at. You are comparing 'to' with 'so' to indicate the final state that those words intend to express.  Thank you for the new phrase 'make it so'.  One phrase I know from the Star Trek is 'Beam me up, Scotty',  which I understand to mean 'get me out of here'.  Thank you.
